# Ionic 2 - Taking more than 30 seconds to run

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ionic project with around 40-50 views. The problem is that it is taking too much time to boot. Not less than 30 seconds. At first I was getting `connection time out error` and I had add   `<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="70000" />` in config.xml to fix that.

On IOS and on Android the boot is almost the same. I have enabled the `enableProdMode();` in the main.ts file.

I ran : `Cordova run android --prod` but still no help.

How can I debug and see what is causing the issue ?

I checked main.js file and it is around 9mb. I am not sure if it big or no

Comment: see first i also suffered with the same later i applied these things    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" /> & <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" /> in android config now it is working fine

Comment: I corrected the question. I have already the done the things you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Does your app define all the pages/views in the app.module.ts file?  If so, you'd almost certainly gain some efficiencies by implementing lazy loading.  Ionic helps you do this with their `IonicPage` component:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/

Comment: Yes I defined all of them in app.module. I have like 60-70 views. I will try to do the lazy loading. I am not sure if it is easy.

Comment: I was reading. Would it be a plugin issue? or this is something natural.

Comment: @MissakBoyajian - it isn't too difficult to swap to lazy loading.  You should be able to experiment with 1 page to start, then once you get the pattern then copy it to the other 60-70 views.  I'm sure that's part of the problem.  Plugins can also cause slow startup time too, so tough to tell which is the major pain point without more info.